# Multiply models in one map?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

I want to show a house and a city/sights in one map.

my controller:

```
@house = House.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @city = City.find(1)
    @location = @house.location
    @location1 = @city.location

    records = @location || @location1 

@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(records) do |location, marker|
      marker.lat location.latitude
      marker.lng location.longitude

    end
```

View

```
<header>
  <h3 class='text'>
    <%= t('navigation.sub_nav.location') %>
  </h3>
<div id="map" style='width: 100%; height: 400px; margin-top: 10px;' ></div>

<script type=text/javascript> 
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
      markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
      handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();
      handler.getMap().setZoom(7);
    });
</script>
```

i shows only the house in the map and not the city. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You probably need `records = @location + @location1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`||` means *or* , so `records = @location || @location1` means assign `@location` to `records`, unless it is nil, in which case assign `@location1` to `records`.

As it appears that either can be nil, I would recommend replacing that line with:

`records = [@location, @location1].compact`, which will assign them both, and remove any nil values. Now, `Gmaps4rails.build_markers(records)` will recieve a proper array for `records`.

You could add some additional checking, if you expect they could ever both be blank (in which case you would have an empty array).

Also, depending on what the rest of your view looks like, `@house`, `@city`, `@location`, and `@location1` may have excessive scope, and can probably be changed to `house`, `city`, `location`, and `location1` if they are only used in the controller.

Comment: brad...it works when i receive 1 record...but when @location1 has multiply records (sights)  i get a no method error...do you know this?

Comment: @Remco Hard to say without seeing more of your code. This would probably be better as a new question, but I would consider trying `[@location, @location1].flatten.compact`.